# How not to display null values in json as response from jax-rs

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

I'm using jax rs and I want to create responses as json, code:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class Rest{
@GET
Path("/Test")
public RestResponse restTest(){
return new RestResponse(100,"ERROR");
}
}

@XmlRootElement()
public class RestResponse{
private Integer code;
private String status;
private Integer id;

public RestResponse(Integer code, String status){
this.code = code;
this.status = status;
}
}
```

and I'm getting response as :
`{"status":"ERROR","code":100,"id":null}`

how to remove that `"id":null` value?
I want response to looks as :
`{"status":"ERROR","code":100}`

I need it because sometimes id is null and sometimes code is null and I don't want to display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Genson](http://code.google.com/p/genson/) you could do it like that:

```
// register a provider for your custom genson configuration.
@Provider
public class GensonCustomResolver implements ContextResolver<Genson> {
  // configure the Genson instance
  private final Genson genson = new Genson.Builder()
                                        // if you want to support JAXB annotations
                                        .with(new JAXBBundle())
                                        .setSkipNull(true)
                                        .create();

  @Override
  public Genson getContext(Class<?> type) {
    return genson;
  }
}
```

Comment: omg that is so simply and powerfull, it makes me life easier thanks again